# How to get tracing info for binding variables passed through OracleParameter in ODP.NET?

Tags: sql, oracle, odp.net, trace, bind-variables

After Googling a lot and not finding what I'm looking for I decided to ask this question.

I'm using *binding variables* as demonstrated in this awesome article from **2005** titled [The Values That Bind](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-sep/o55odpnet-101704.html) by Mark A. Williams, like this:

```
OracleParameter p_APP_NAME =
    new OracleParameter("p_APP_NAME", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
                         p_APP_NAME.Size = 50;
                         p_APP_NAME.Value = log.Application.Name;
                         cmd.Parameters.Add(p_APP_NAME);
```

I successfully enabled [`ODP.NET` debug tracing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e18754/featDebug.htm) but one key info that's missing is that the logged `SQL statement` doesn't show me what was the value bound to the binding variable.

It's logging `OracleCommand.CommandText` but without `OracleCommand.Parameters` values. It's showing me this:

```
TIME:2013/09/20-22:59:21:890 TID:20fc  OpsSqlPrepare2(): SQL: UPDATE PS_LOG SET 
                                              APP_NAME = :p_APP_NAME, 
                                              WHERE LOG_ID = :p_LOG_ID
```

What I'd really like to see are the actual values that were used in the query sent to the ORACLE server like this:

```
TIME:2013/09/20-22:59:21:890 TID:20fc  OpsSqlPrepare2(): SQL: UPDATE PS_LOG SET 
                                              APP_NAME = 'App Name', 
                                              WHERE LOG_ID = 777
```

Am I missing some configuration or this info I want is not available when using `ODP.NET` tracing capability?

If this is not built-in I guess I'll have to implement my own substitution method and log the `SQL Statement` myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As one of the options, you could turn on sql tracing with bind variables dumping by setting 10046  event of level 12 or 4 for a session, either manually or automatically(in a logon trigger for a user for instance):

```
alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 12';
```

After that trace file will be generated in a directory specified by `user_dump_dest` parameter.

```
SQL> show parameter user_dump_dest;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE                          
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------ 
user_dump_dest                       string      D:\...\diag\rdbms\cdb\cdb 
                                                 \trace
```

Here is an example:

```
SQL> alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 12';
  2 variable var number;
  3 exec :var := 1234567;     -- our bind variable
  4 select 1 from dual where 1234567 = :var ;
```

Among other information presented in a newly generated trace file we could find information about the query, bind variable(s) and its/their values:

> PARSING IN CURSOR #375980232 len=40 dep=0 uid=103
>                   oct=3 lid=103 tim=2640550035 hv=1641534478
>  
>                   ad='7ff5bd0baf0' sqlid='ap9rzz5hxgp0f'
>   **select 1 from dual where 1234567 = :var**            *<-- our query*
>  
>       END OF STMT
>       PARSE #375980232:c=0,e=375,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=1,r=0,dep=0,og=1,plh=0,tim=2640550034
>       BINDS #375980232:
>        Bind#0
>         oacdty=02 mxl=22(22) mxlc=00 mal=00 scl=00 pre=00
>         oacflg=03 fl2=1000000 frm=01 csi=178 siz=24 off=0
>         kxsbbbfp=16646e10  bln=22  avl=05  flg=05
>         **value=1234567**      <-- value of the bind variable

You could also, starting from Oracle 10g and up, query `v$sql_bind_capture` dynamic performance view to get information about bind variable(s) and their values:

```
select t.parsing_user_id
     , t.sql_fulltext         -- text of a query
     , bc.name                -- name of a bind variable
     , bc.value_string        -- value of a bind variable
  from v$sqlarea t
  join v$sql_bind_capture bc
    on (bc.sql_id = t.sql_id)
  join v$session s
    on (s.user# = t.parsing_schema_id)
  where s.username = user
    and bc.name in (':VAR') -- name of a bind variable(s), 
                            -- value(s) of which we want to know
```

Result:

```
PARSING_USER_ID   SQL_FULLTEXT                      NAME    VALUE_STRING   
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
           103   select 1 from dual where 1 =:var  :VAR     1234567
```

Comment: Pretty nice Nicholas. I had read about these options but I was curious to know if there was a missing/hidden config that would allow me to get the binding info out of the box using the standard `ODP.NET` tracing. They could add a new trace level to show that info, shouldn't they? At least we have options to grab that info and this is great. I'll try these options ASAP. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with everything posted by Nicholas but would add that beginning with Oracle 10.1 the [DBMS_MONITOR PL/SQL Package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17602/d_monitor.htm#i1003993) is the preferred method of enabling/disabling tracing. Though setting the event still works as Nicholas has nicely demonstrated.

As you have observed ODP does not emit bind variable values into its trace file as a security consideration.

Comment: Great! I know this answer was provided by Mark A. Williams (the author of that article mentioned in my question). I got in contact with him through e-mail and asked him to provide his insights regarding this matter. He replied the e-mail and told me he just answered it. How privileged I'm! :D