# Oracle - Log the executed query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have to debug stored procedure which contains a few SQL queries. One of them contains an error. So, I need to execute this SQL query with parameters in other window. I found next query that would help me:

```
select v.SQL_TEXT
from v$sql v
```

Unfortunately, this field restricted by 1Kb. In my case I have quite big SQL query and Oracle truncates it. How to log the executed query? I use PL/SQL Developer 10 and Oracle 9i

Comment: what do you mean by logging sql query  ? :s

Comment: @jWeaver, something like exporting SQL query with parameters from stored procedure to .txt. For example,  `select * from employee e where e.id=vID` to **select * from employee e where e.id=15**

Comment: enable tracing with bind parameters and run tkprof on the output http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928230/how-to-get-tracing-info-for-binding-variables-passed-through-oracleparameter-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unfortunately, this field restricted by 1Kb

If you need the full SQL, then use the **SQL_FULLTEXT** which is a CLOB datatype instead of `SQL_TEXT` whcih is limited to first 1000 characters.

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2113.htm#REFRN30246),

```
Column          Datatype        Description
------          --------------  ---------------------------------------

SQL_TEXT        VARCHAR2(1000)  First thousand characters of the SQL 
                                text for the current cursor

SQL_FULLTEXT    CLOB            Full text for the SQL statement exposed 
                                as a CLOB column. The full text of a SQL
                                statement can be retrieved using this 
                                column instead of joining with the 
                                V$SQL_TEXT dynamic performance view.
```

So, use:

```
SELECT SQL_FULLTEXT FROM v$sql;
```

By the way, seems like you are actually looking for tracing your session to get the complete details of the procedure and the SQL statements involved. I would suggest to trace the session with **level 4** i.e. with the addition of **bind variable values**.

See [How to generate trace file – SQL Trace and TKPROF in Oracle](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/how-to-generate-trace-file-sql-trace-and-tkprof-in-oracle/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have permission to server to see trace file. So, I can use only one way which is **v$sql** table, and it's much easily in my opinion. I'm going to try your solution tomorrow. If it works, I'll check your answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: In Oracle 9i which I use there is no **SQL_FULLTEXT** field. I need to find another way!

Comment: Did you try `v$sql_text`?

Comment: Did you mean `v$sqltext`? Yes, there is **SQL_TEXT** field which is restricted by 64 bytes. I begin hating Oracle 9i

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a 9i instance to check. By the way Oracle 9i is desupported.